# Monitor log file event it was deleted and created again

Tags: 16.04, logging, tail

I do file monitor with help of command:

```
tail -f foo.csv
```

After logging program restart file is deleted and created new one with the same name. But monitor window stops showing records of newly created file and remains with old file info. How to proceed my terminal window to show new records even file was deleted and for some small period of time?

Answer (score 0):

Tail is still looking at the file that was deleted. Defaut behavior. What you want is the `--follow=foo.csv` option which follows the name not the descriptor. `see man tail`.

> With  --follow  (-f), tail defaults to following the file descriptor,
>   which means that even if a tail'ed file is renamed, tail will 
>   continue  to  track  its  end. This  default  behavior is not
>   desirable when you really want to track the actual name of the file,
>   not the file  descriptor  (e.g.,  log  rotation).   Use  --follow=name
>   in  that  case.  That causes tail to track the named file in a way
>   that accommodates renaming, removal and creation.